# redux-form with mapstatetoprops not firing onSubmit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am using redux-form and also making a get request in the background to fetch a list of categories from an api. When I hook up mapStateToProps, I have to do some 'hacky' stuff to get the render method to acknowledge my served categories. However now that I have the categories rendering properly my onSubmit function is not being called. Below is my form, followed by my export statement, as it currently is, followed by what it was when it actually worked ie made the submit but did not have mapStateToProps hooked up. I also changed my export statement to what it is now based on what I read here [initial values with redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/3491)

```
renderCategories(field) {
        return (
            <div>
                <select>
                    <option value=''>Select A category</option>
                        {_.map(field.categories, category => {
                            return (<option value={category.id} key={category.id}>{category.name}</option>);
                        })}
               </select>
            </div>
       );
}

onSubmit(values) {
    console.log('we made it to onSubmit: ', values)
    this.props.createContact(values);
}

render(){
    const { handleSubmit, categories } = this.props;
    if(!categories.length) {
        return <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))}>
                <Field
                    label='First Name' 
                    name='firstName'
                    component={this.renderField} 
                />
                <Field
                    label='Last Name' 
                    name='lastName'
                    component={this.renderField} 
                />
                <Field
                    label='Email' 
                    name='emailAddresses'
                    component={this.renderField} 
                />
                <Field
                    label='Categories' 
                    name='categories'
                    props={{categories}}
                    component={this.renderCategories} 
                />
                <button type='submit' className='btn btn-primary'>CREATE CONTACT</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Current export statement, no working onSubmit

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {createContact, fetchCategories})(
    reduxForm({
        validate,
        form: 'NewContactForm',
    })(NewContact));
```

Old export statement, without mapStateToProps but with working submit

```
export default reduxForm({
   validate,
   form: 'NewContactForm'
})(
  connect(null, { createContact })(NewContact)
);
```

Comment: Are you aware that you're calling (not referencing) `handleSubmit` when you do `handleSubmit(this.onSubmit.bind(this))`? Maybe this is a redux-form specific thing, but usually you would do `onSubmit={onSubmit}` and then define the method like this in the component: `onSubmit = (submitEvent) => { this.props.handleSubmit(); };`.

Comment: where is your `onSubmit` defined?